# how can i replace the front airlift air bags on my 1982 chevrolet p30 chassis ,

Tags: chevrolet, suspension

to mechanics stack exchange , I hope this will clarify my question I,ve really tried to explain the situation , please critique , thank you

how can I install front airlift air bags in a 1982 Chevrolet p30 chassis , since air lift lied about installation of airbag through the small 2 inch circle on the lower A arm,  the airbag is placed inside the coil spring, so instead i,ll have to make a complete disassembly of the a-arm lower to me it looks like the removal of big sway bar which attaches to the lower a arms then remove the shock absorber,s, also the tie rod link,s, and i,m confused about the lower a arm disassembly the lower ball joint to release and drop the lower a arm and get the coil spring out and put the airlift bag back inside the coil spring and bolt everything back up in some certain order of re-assembly

the rv front end is jacked up with 2 jack stands and wooden blocks , and heavy concrete blocks as a back up, i have a floor jac and 10 ton,12 ton bottle jacks in support as well, the wheels are off the ground and I can access the complete front end

to send you a picture , i,m not familiar with sending pictures I would have to learn what to do ,not to good on the computer, but this is a typical southwind or bounder from the 1980,s , mines an 1982 with 454 and it runs very well, problem is very mushy front suspension.

this is a dangerous job , I,m disabled with most tools, might need a pickle bar for the tie rods, and hopefully don't need a spring compressor.i haven't been able to secure help, living miles from any real qualified mechanics,in a very remote area, cant even get mobile phone service in the area. please consider helping ME GET THIS STRAIGHT , I,m a first responder had a  terrible political vendetta  and disabilities , they sabotaged just about the whole rv , and every physics projects i was heir too,

so i,m ready to unbolt and drop sway bar , and shocks , I understand if I use a pickle bar on tie rod link I,ll have to replace the bushings,is that true??

the big deal is the wheel hub or spindle disassembly to lower and release the a arm can I just release the spindle lower ball joint and drop the lower a arm to get the coil spring out and load the airlift bag, back into the coil thanks for any help really, thanks people I really hope we can communicate with this new edit on the question ,

suspension

Comment: Two things would really help here: 1) can you get pictures of what you're trying to do? 2) can you link to the product you are trying to install?

Comment: [This video might be of help to you.](https://youtu.be/vE20DUy5njk?t=10m25s) I've positioned it at the point where he's stuffing it up through the hole in the bottom of the spring perch on the lower A-arm. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: thanks to paulster, yes this is precisely the situation , same front suspension ,same airlift bags,  same circumstance with the center hole in the lower a arm for the hopeful replacement of the airlift bag

Comment: so I,ve tried to roll the bags up with 1/4 inch tie straps as shown ,

Comment: and it has not worked the holes are just not large enough , I,m about to boil the bags in hot water supposedly they become more pliant , I,ve even tried to force the bags inside the coil with a scissors jack placed beneath to push the bag up and inside , I,ve used dishwasher soap which is slippery , better than an oil .,  so airlift says dismantle the lower a arm and this truly appears too be the situation at the moment

Comment: my thanks for your concern , looks like i have to disassemble the a-arm and further paulster, I,ve been involved in lots of technology you might be intererested to learn about , some very advanced

Comment: You might just have to dismantle, as much as you don't want to.